# É possível colocar uma condição "IF" em meios aos inner joins e outras condições de um where no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um procedimento que recebe um parâmetro que pode ser 0, 1 ou 2. Quando é 1 ou 0, ele precisa considerar a linha onde tem "and bol_portfolio = @eh_port", mas quando é 2, ele não pode entrar nessa condição, apenas ignorando este código. Isso é possível? Queria apenas uma condição simples que fizesse o banco ignorar esta linha caso o parâmetro seja 2.

Comment: Você está usando Stored Procedures?

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar a pergunta como respondida caso encontrou alguma alternativa the lhe foi satisfatória

Comment: @jefissu nem vota nas resposta ele votou, imagina escolhe a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Maneira mais simples:

```
 and (bol_portfolio = @eh_port or @eh_port = 2)
```

Neste caso nem de procedure você precisaria para validá-la, pois quando o parâmetro valer dois a comparação com o bol_portfolio será ignorada.

Editado

Detalhe: Oracle sql valida da direita para esquerda, ou seja, se @eh_port for 2, ele nem realizará a comparação com bol_portifolio

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode usar um CASE

```
and bol_portfolio = CASE WHEN @eh_port = 1 or @eh_port = 0
                         THEN @eh_port
                         ELSE bol_portfolio END
```

Quando for 2 vai para o else e nao vai considerar seu parametro.

Answer (score 0):

De uma olhada no comando IF do Transact-SQL.
Exemplo:

```
IF LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@REV)))=0 BEGIN
     <Seu codigo SQL>
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma das maneiras de se fazer isso é criar uma String dinamicamente e utilizar a Stored Procedure `sp_executesql` para executar o SQL que está nessa String.

Veja um exemplo:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @EH_PORT INT
DECLARE @ID INT

SET @EH_PORT = 2
SET @ID = 15

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM TABELA '

IF @EH_PORT = 2 
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'WHERE ID = ' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(10))
END

print @SQL

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ID int',
                   @ID
```

Isso eu fazia há muito tempo no SQL Server 2005. Não sei se nas versões mais novas existem maneiras mais fáceis de fazer.

Eu também utilizava isso para casos onde a Stored Procedure deveria rodar pra bancos de dados distintos (embora na mesma instância). Assim, até o nome do banco era possível parametrizar. Veja exemplo:

```
'FROM [' + @DATABASE + '].[dbo].[' + @TABELA_CT2 + '] CT2,  [' + @DATABASE + '].[dbo].[CTS020] CTS'
```